# Estoy haciendo la operación de suma, resta y multiplicación con componentes en vuejs, corre pero me marca error al inspeccionar

Tags: javascript, html, html5, nodejs, vue.js

Quiero hacer suma, resta y multiplicación con componentes en vuejs, ejecuto mi código y funciona, hace lo que quiero, pero si inspecciono en el navegador me dice que "operacion" no es una función y es la función que uso para que corra, si me pueden corregir dicho error, agradezco, adjunto mi HTML y JS adelante.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>VueJS Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <operaciones></operaciones>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('operaciones', {
    props: ['value0', 'value1'],
    template: `
<div>
<input type="number" :value="value0" @input="numberone = $event.target.value" >
<input type="number" :value="value1" @input="numbertwo = $event.target.value" >
<button v-on:click="operacion()">Resolver</button>
<p>Suma: {{mensaje}}</p>
<p>Resta: {{mensaje2}}</p>
<p>Multiplicación: {{mensaje3}}</p>
</div>
`,
    data: function () {
        return {
            numberone: null,
            numbertwo: null,
            mensaje: null,
            mensaje2: null,
            mensaje3: null
        }
    },
    computed: {
        operacion() {
            this.mensaje = parseInt(this.numberone) +
                parseInt(this.numbertwo);
            this.mensaje2 = parseInt(this.numberone) -
                parseInt(this.numbertwo);
            this.mensaje3 = parseInt(this.numberone) *
                parseInt(this.numbertwo);
        }
    },
})
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe utilizar methods en lugar de computed. Los computed tienen una finalidad diferente como lo indica la documentación de vue : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

```
Vue.component('operaciones', {
    props: ['value0', 'value1'],
    template: `
<div>
<input type="number" :value="value0" @input="numberone = $event.target.value" >
<input type="number" :value="value1" @input="numbertwo = $event.target.value" >
<button v-on:click="operacion()">Resolver</button>
<p>Suma: {{mensaje}}</p>
<p>Resta: {{mensaje2}}</p>
<p>Multiplicación: {{mensaje3}}</p>
</div>
`,
    data: function () {
        return {
            numberone: null,
            numbertwo: null,
            mensaje: null,
            mensaje2: null,
            mensaje3: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        operacion() {
            this.mensaje = parseInt(this.numberone) +
                parseInt(this.numbertwo);
            this.mensaje2 = parseInt(this.numberone) -
                parseInt(this.numbertwo);
            this.mensaje3 = parseInt(this.numberone) *
                parseInt(this.numbertwo);
        }
    },
})
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```